# Which neural network architectures are there that perform 3D convolutions?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request, model-request, 3d-convolution

I am trying to do **3d image deconvolution** using **convolution neural network**. But I cannot find many famous CNNs that perform a 3d convolution. Can anyone point out some for me?

Background: I am using PyTorch, but any language is OK. What I want to know most is the network structure. I can't find papers on this topic.

Links to research papers would be especially appreciated.

Comment: See [Learning Descriptor Networks for 3D Shape Synthesis and Analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00586).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches for training CNN on 3d data, but the decision to use a particular architecture is heavily dependant upon the format of your dataset.

If you are using 3d point cloud data, I would suggest you go through [PointNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593) and [PointCNN](https://github.com/yangyanli/PointCNN).

But training a CNN on 3d point clouds is very tough.

There is also a way to train CNNs by posing the 3d structure from different viewpoints ([Multiview CNNs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00880.pdf)).

But remember that training CNN on 3d data is really a tough task.

If you plan to use a voxelized input data format, I suggest going through [VoxelNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.06396).

Since you are mentioning deconvolution, the most relevant paper I can come across is [3D U-Net: Learning Dense Volumetric Segmentation from Sparse Annotation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06650).

But deconvolution in its own right is a very expensive operation, which acting on 3d data makes it very hard, so I would suggest you check for alternate methods.

Comment: Thanks! And for the last sentence, I understand the 3d convolution is a memory consuming operation. Is it because of that that you say it is hard. And also what is the alternate methods except optimization methods like RLTV and etc. ? Thanks again

Comment: yes , deconvolution is more consuming than convolution due to upsampling involved in it . regarding optimization methods i don't know much. PS: can you expand RLTV so that i can check?

Comment: why is it difficult to learn on from 3D data?